# Is there an equivalent of jQuery().text() that doesn't include all descendants?

Tags: jquery

For example, given the following HTML:

```
<a id="test" href="#">Text of A <span>(span text)</span></a>
```

Then `jQuery('#test').text()` will return `'Text of A (span text)'`, is there a way to get just `'Text of A '` (the text inside the `<a>` tag and not in it's descendant `<span>` tag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a conversation that solves your problem:
[select top level nodetext is not supported with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020931/select-top-level-nodetext-is-not-supported-with-jquery)

Here is an excerpt:

```
$("#hello").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable way to do this by making a simple plugin:

**Plugin**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.directText = function () {
        var o = "";
        this.each(function () {
            var nodes = this.childNodes;
            for (var i = 0; i <= nodes.length - 1; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].nodeType == 3) o += nodes[i].nodeValue;
            }
        });
        return $.trim(o);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Usage**

```
$("#myElement").directText();
```

### *DEMO ==>* http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/8X9LC/