# Strip content of specific tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can strip the html correctly out of a string doing this:

```
HtmlToText = function(html){
    return jQuery(html).text();
};
```

but there is cases then the HTML string containing styling like:

```
<style type="text/css">
.button:hover {
    background-color: #6B6D71;
}
</style>
```

the function will strip the `<style>` tags but my text will end up with
`.button:hover {
        background-color: #6B6D71;
 }`

I'll like to know if jQuery is able to strip styles too and how.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020931 You can expand the answers provided there to filter children based on their tag types (or any valid jQuery selector, really)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.clone()` and remove the style tags from that using `.remove()`.

```
var $foo = $('.foo'),
    $fooClone = $foo.clone();

$fooClone.find('style').remove();

$('#output').text($fooClone.text());
```

Here is a small demo: http://jsbin.com/lamasabapu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `remove()` method to target just style tags without much overhead cost:

```
HtmlToText = function(html){
    return jQuery(html).remove('style').text();
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u7vgj65u/)

Comment: loved the demo link to JSFiddle, but @Bill Criswell answered first.

Comment: Fair enough, but clone isn't necessary here.

Comment: Agreed. I just assumed I was working on an element I didn't want to alter. It looks like you just want to do it to a fragment of html.

Comment: Actually, `.remove('style')` does not seem to be working. I had to approach it like this: http://jsbin.com/dovuvuwova/1/edit?html,js,output